# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in React when importing JSS file using material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx, jss

I am trying to import my jss file to React component (.jsx) and I have this error :

[image]

I looked through related questions and I tried all solutions, mostly about updating versions of material-ui. Here is my package.json file:

[image]

the way I write jss file :

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';



const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: 
    {
        margin: '10px'
    }
}));

export default useStyles;
```

And jsx file :

```
import React from 'react';
import DateBar from './DateBar';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import useStyles from './Board.jss';



export default function Board()
{
    const classes = useStyles();
    return(
...
```

Am I missing something or Do I need additional packages for using jsx and jss in React?

I have been trying all the solutions but didn't work..

Note: When I put the code inside of Jss into Jsx file, code works fine. Importing/Exporting might be an issue..

Edit: Still couldn't fix even though I created a new app and installed dependancies from the beginning..

Comment: Try to use useStyles directly like this: useStyles.root

Comment: @RafaelMora didn't work unfortunately..

Comment: Do a console.log(useStyles) what do you get?

Comment: I have this: 
/static/media/Board.f1afab75.jss
@RafaelMora

Comment: That is the problem, you are getting the path. Maybe is because your import doesn't know how to load that file, are you using a bundler? Why the '.jss' extension?? Why not just '.js' ?

Comment: @RafaelMora No, I don't use bundler I guess. Because it has css in it..

Comment: You don't need that extension I guess, try changing the extension to '.js'

Comment: @RafaelMora didn't work either.

Comment: try this: import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

Comment: @AmirhosseinEbrahimi tried as well, didn't work. The problem is importing JSS file into JSX because it is supposed to return a function but instead, it returns a path as I mentioned above..

Comment: Try using babel to transpile